# Vertx merge contents of multiple files in single file

Tags: vert.x

What is the best way to append the contents of multiple files into single file in vertx? I have tried vertx **filesystem** and **asyncFile** but both do not have a option to append file or I did not know of any. Is there any alternative approach to merge or append files in vertx asynchronously.

The only solution I could find is to make buffer list and write content on the end of each previous buffer length using loop.

Comment: Appending asynchronously means that you don't care about the order files will be appended. Is that correct in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as of Vert.x 3.4, there is no helper method on `FileSystem` to append a file to another file.

You could do it with `AsyncFile` and `Pump` as follows.

First create a utility method to open files:

```
Future<AsyncFile> openFile(FileSystem fileSystem, String path, OpenOptions openOptions) {
  Future<AsyncFile> future = Future.future();
  fileSystem.open(path, openOptions, future);
  return future;
}
```

Then another one to append a file to another file with a `Pump`:

```
Future<AsyncFile> append(AsyncFile source, AsyncFile destination) {
  Future<AsyncFile> future = Future.future();
  Pump pump = Pump.pump(source, destination);
  source.exceptionHandler(future::fail);
  destination.exceptionHandler(future::fail);
  source.endHandler(v -> future.complete(destination));
  pump.start();
  return future;
}
```

Now you can combine those with *sequential composition*:

```
void merge(FileSystem fileSystem, String output, List<String> sources) {
  openFile(fileSystem, output, new OpenOptions().setCreate(true).setTruncateExisting(true).setWrite(true)).compose(outFile -> {
    Future<AsyncFile> mergeFuture = null;
    for (String source : sources) {
      if (mergeFuture == null) {
        mergeFuture = openFile(fileSystem, source, new OpenOptions()).compose(sourceFile -> {
          return append(sourceFile, outFile);
        });
      } else {
        mergeFuture = mergeFuture.compose(v -> {
          return openFile(fileSystem, source, new OpenOptions()).compose(sourceFile -> {
            return append(sourceFile, outFile);
          });
        });
      }
    }
    return mergeFuture;
  }).setHandler(ar -> {
    System.out.println("Done");
  });
}
```